# FullCalendar Daylight Saving moving events back 1 day

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, fullcalendar

I have been testing my implementation of FullCalendar and previously, through Februrary and most of March, when adding an event on a particular day, the event rendered on the correct day.

However, now I have been testing it on days in April (since daylight saving has kicked in) and whenever I click on a date and add an event, it renders on the previous day.

How can I fix this issue? I cannot get my head around it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use additional JS library like `moment.js` (http://momentjs.com/docs/). It has functionality for configuring daylight saving. But in general you have to solve it manually in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but I had a brainwave.

I used:

```
if (TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(item.Date))
```

To detect if the date I want to add an event on is in DST, if it is, I added a day onto the displayed event start and end and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

i had the some problem yesterday. i solved by doing following.

```
  public static string GetFullCalenderFormat()
            {
                return @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz";
            }
```

Then

```
someEventDate.ToString(GetFullCalenderFormat());
```